# Restore mmssms.db without root?

Tags: root-access, backup, sms

So I have managed to get this file from a broken install, I'd like to restore my sms but I don't want to root my phone. How can I manage this ?

I've thought about converting to xml and using sms backup and restore but this will be tedious because of the format converting.

What else do you suggest ?

Comment: copy it to another device which is rooted and export xml

Comment: "another rooted device" can also be a rooted emulator...

Comment: I didn't work of course, I posted my solution

Answer (score 1):

So I decided to export the SQL data as CSV and then imported in Excel.
I then checked the XML format from SMS backup and Restore, made it match, exported it as XML from Excel.
And finally you can just restore it.

Comment: good. please make this answer useful for others. How did you export csv? which tables/columns did you use, and how did you sort to made it match? how did you export xml?